# Prism + Wpf : Nested region not loaded by RegionManager

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, prism

I have four(4) regions in my shell:

1. `RibbonViewRegion` : To inject tabs
2. `RibbonTabRegion` :  To inject group of controls
3. `RibbonGroupRegion` : To inject one control (button, combobox,...)
4. `ContentRegion` : main content region

   `<telerik:RadRibbonView prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.RibbonViewRegion}" ApplicationName="Demo">
       <telerik:RadRibbonTab Header="Principal" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.RibbonTabRegion}">
           <telerik:RadRibbonGroup Header="Navigation" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.RibbonGroupRegion}"/>
       </telerik:RadRibbonTab>
   </telerik:RadRibbonView>
   <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MainContentRegion}"/>`

In module **Initialize** method, when i inject my view like this:

```
RegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.RibbonGroupRegion].Add(Container.Resolve<MyView>());
```

an exception occurs:

> An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in Prism.Wpf.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: 
>   The region manager does not contain the RibbonGroupRegion region.

Effectively: when I set a break point at this line, I notice there is only three regions loaded - `RibbonViewRegion`, `RibbonTabRegion` and `ContentRegion`

**my question is:** why my `RibbonGroupRegion` is not loaded by `RegionManager` ?

**note**: i implemented the `RadRibbonGroupRegionAdapter` and it works fine.

guide me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it, I replaced this code :

```
RegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.RibbonGroupRegion].Add(Container.Resolve<MyView>());
```

by this :

```
RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.RibbonGroupRegion, () => Container.Resolve<MyView>());
```

and it works